# How to fill in records where dates have overlapped

Tags: sql, sql-server

Working with healthcare data in SQL and I'm trying to fill in records when there are overlapping dates for thousands of records. This mostly occurs when a patient is in a nursing home and then transferred to a hospital. They have not been discharged yet from the nursing home because their bed is being kept available for them, so that's why the discharge date is missing. Here's one example of what the records look like:

| Patient | Admission_Date | Discharge_Date | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 1/2/2021 | MISSING | NURSING HOME |
| ABC | 2/3/2021 | 2/4/2021 | ICU |
| ABC | 4/10/2021 | 4/13/2021 | HOSPITAL |

Here's what I need it to look like:

| Patient | Admission_Date | Discharge_Date | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 1/2/2021 | 2/3/2021 | NURSING HOME |
| ABC | 2/3/2021 | 2/4/2021 | ICU |
| ABC | 2/4/2021 | 4/10/2021 | NURSING HOME |
| ABC | 4/10/2021 | 4/13/2021 | HOSPITAL |
| ABC | 4/13/2021 | MISSING | NURSING HOME |

Any ideas on how to get this done?

I've tried using a combination of multiple CASE WHEN statements and lag/leads but it's obviously very inefficient and difficult to account for all of the possible records between nursing home stays.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this with plain sql. you'll have to make use of a stored procedure or function (build out a timeline and insert missing time entries).

Comment: can there be multiple NULL discharge dates per patient?

Comment: So anywhere we have an admission without a discharge date, and subsequent encounters, we are behaving as though there _were_ a discharge date starting at the date of the next encounter's admit date?

Comment: @siggemannen that is possible. One example would be a very recent admission to the hospital after being transferred from the nursing home. The nursing.home admission is still open to keep the bed available and if the patient hasn't been discharged from the hospital yet then that would be 2 NULL discharge dates.

Comment: @Xedni yes. We have no way of knowing the exact transfer out times from nursing home to hospital and vice versa. So the next best thing is to create new admission and discharge dates based on what we have.

Answer (score 0):

For the exact example from above the solution is here. I haven't tested it for multiple patients or multiple missing dates. But I can, if it's not enough.

```
CREATE TABLE Patient_Locations (
    Patient nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
  , Admission_Date date NOT NULL
  , Discharge_Date date NULL
  , Location nvarchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO Patient_Locations (Patient, Admission_Date, Discharge_Date, Location)
VALUES ('ABC',  '20210102', NULL, 'NURSING HOME')
     , ('ABC',  '20210203', '20210204', 'ICU')
     , ('ABC',  '20210410', '20210413', 'HOSPITAL')

;WITH Next_Known_Dates (Patient, Admission_Date, Discharge_Date, Location, NEXT_Admission_Date)
AS (
    SELECT Patient
         , Admission_Date
         , Discharge_Date
         , Location
         , NEXT_Admission_Date = LEAD(Admission_Date, 1) OVER (Partition by Patient ORDER BY Admission_Date)
    FROM Patient_Locations
)
-- First row where Discharge_Date is Missing. Replace by next known period
SELECT Patient
     , Admission_Date
     , Discharge_Date = NEXT_Admission_Date
     , Location
FROM Next_Known_Dates
WHERE Discharge_Date IS NULL
UNION ALL
-- Just normal rows
SELECT Patient
     , Admission_Date
     , Discharge_Date
     , Location
FROM Patient_Locations
WHERE Discharge_Date IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
--Little magic. Replace missing dates with 'normal' Discharge_date and NEXT_Admission_Date
SELECT Patient_Locations.Patient
     , Next_Known_Dates.Discharge_Date
     , Next_Known_Dates.NEXT_Admission_Date
     , Patient_Locations.Location
FROM Patient_Locations
JOIN Next_Known_Dates 
  ON Next_Known_Dates.Patient = Patient_Locations.Patient
 AND Next_Known_Dates.Admission_Date > Patient_Locations.Admission_Date
WHERE Patient_Locations.Discharge_Date IS NULL
  AND Next_Known_Dates.Discharge_Date  IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

You can try it here:
https://sqlize.online/sql/mssql2022/14e363a81956b2e9019fc44daf47a8c7/

Look at this select for the Idea of a new column NEXT_Admission_Date:

```
SELECT Patient
     , Admission_Date
     , Discharge_Date
     , Location
     , NEXT_Admission_Date = LEAD(Admission_Date, 1) OVER (Partition by Patient ORDER BY Admission_Date)
FROM Patient_Locations
```